# AngularJS - Evaluating the return value from a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a directive that calculates my duration of stay and throws out an answer in months if less than 12months, or in years if greater than 12months. For example:

```
<p calculate-duration></p>
```

Can return:

```
5months
```

or

```
9months
```

or

```
3years
```

How can i perform a condition (ng-show) on the above directive, that when the result value is greater than 2years? The DIV containing "My text to show" is visible.

I've tried:

```
<div ng-show="calculate-duration > 2years">My text to show</div>
```

Comment: Some 99,99% we are dealing with XY problem here.

Comment: @arturgrzesiak - what does that mean?

Comment: [XY problem] (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) -- basically instead of describing what you tried, explain what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: @arturgrzesiak - Updated with: How can i perform a condition (ng-show) on the above directive, that when the result value is greater than 2years? The DIV containing "My text to show" is visible.

Comment: Could you show us some pseudo code or a fiddle? It'sv ery hard to tell what exactly you want to do. Are the show and your directive on the same element? Is your directive isolated? etc.

Answer (score 0):

No, a directive does not 'Return' a value.

Do you own the calculate-duration directive ?
If yes, it wont be hard to add the logic to simply hide/show the element conditionally.

An alternative is, to write a new directive. In that new directive, you can use the $compile service to compile the

```
<p calculate-duration></p>
```

string. Base on the result, you can then show/hide the element itself.